# using Boto 3 to get s3 bucket access control information with real only permission on aws account, but unable to get

Tags: amazon-web-services, api

I am using `Boto 3` to get `s3 bucket` access control information with real only permission on `aws` account, but unable to get it and getting an error

```
response2 = client.get_public_access_block(Bucket='BUCKETNAME')    
print(response2['PublicAccessBlockConfiguration']['BlockPublicAcls'])
```

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (NoSuchPublicAccessBlockConfiguration) when calling the GetPublicAccessBlock operation: The public access block configuration was not found

Please suggest what all permissions as AWS Account user I need to get access information of s3 buckets

Answer (score -1):

I had a same problem with boto3. But i resolved the problem, changing region.
so the region us-east-1 doesn't work for it.
Thanks